# Architectural question about user-controlled Docker instances

Tags: docker, service, docker-swarm

I got a website in Laravel where you can click on a button which sends a message to a Python daemon which is isolated in Docker. This works for an easy MVP to prove a concept, but it's not viable in production because a user would most likely want to pause, resume and stop that process as well because that service is designed to never stop otherwise considering it's a scanner which is looped.

I have thought about a couple of solutions for this, such as fixing it in the software layer but that would add complexity to the program. I have googled Docker and I have found that it is actually possible to do what I want to do with Docker itself with the commands pause, unpause, run and kill.

It would be optimal if I had a service which would interact with the Docker instances with the criteria of above and would be able to take commands from HTTP. Is Docker Swarm the right solution for this problem or is there an easier way?

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you say, "a user", what user do you mean? The operations guy running the service? The user of the HTML front-end? If you mean the ops guy, then you have to consider interruptions to your service (because if the service is down, the button won't work). This is covered by the concept of availability (https://itsm.tools/how-to-define-measure-and-report-service-availability/). In general, Swam isn't useful for anything -- the industry has moved on to Kubernetes for high-availability (HA). There are no good reasons for a service to be paused.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean a normal user on the website which has purchased an account. The user should have no privileges beside starting, pausing, resuming, and stopping his scans (Think e.g starting a web crawler from a dashboard). I suppose the pausing and resuming can be redundant by simply saving the service state and using stop and start actions. Would it require a lot of setup for making Kubernetes start and stop a Docker image from a HTTP API?

Comment: In order to respond to any request from a browser, your service *must* be running. Because it's hard to predict the times a user may be using your app, the service is usually running all the time. You don't have a service per user, you just have one and it responds to all users. I'm sorry to say this, but you're about 3-years worth of learning and research away from being able to understand and do this -- you should ignore my previous comments because kubernetes is too advanced for you. I teach this stuff, and it takes recent computer-science master's grads about 6 months to get up to speed.

Comment: I understand that the service must be running to receive the message from the message broker, as of right now I have a service which is always listening to messages but it can only process messages sequentially. I have considered having a pool of services and have automatic scaling, which would solve the scalability issues. But I'm not sure on how to stop a scan from a web user. How would you go about stopping a user-initiated scan which is ran in a service trough Kubernetes? Restarting that service? Or by software, e.g by sending a message or modifying an API which is periodically checked?

Answer (score 0):

There are both significant security and complexity concerns to using Docker this way and I would not recommend it.

The core rule of Docker security has always been, if you can run any `docker` command, then you can easily take over the entire host.  (You cannot prevent someone from `docker run` a container, as container-root, bind-mounting any part of the host filesystem; so they can reset host-root's password in the `/etc/shadow` file to something they know, allow remote-root ssh access, and reboot the host, as one example.)  I'd be *extremely* careful about connecting this ability to my web tier.  Strongly coupling your application to Docker will also make it more difficult to develop and test.

Instead of launching a process per crawling job, a better approach might be to set up some sort of job queue (perhaps RabbitMQ), and have a multi-user worker that pulls jobs from the queue to do work.  You could have a queue per user, and a separate control queue that receives the stop/start/cancel messages.

If you do this:

- You can run your whole application without needing Docker: you need the front-end, the message queue system, and a worker, but these can all run on your local development system
- If you need more crawlers, you can launch more workers (works well with Kubernetes deployments)
- If you're generating too many crawl requests, you can launch fewer workers
- If a worker dies unexpectedly, you can just restart it, and its jobs will still be in the queue
- Nothing needs to keep track of which process or container belongs to a specific end user

Comment: I think this sounds like an optimal solution, it removes a lot of complexity which I'm trying to avoid to the best of my ability. I have a message broker called ZeroMQ which is used when sending the jobs to the worker. What do you mean by "multi-user worker"? Right now the communication works by getting a job from the queue and then saving the result through a REST API. From my current understanding queues are defined at the start of the program, how would user queues work (e.g for new users)?